# Adapting Fisheye camera from Blender Cycles to Blender Render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I made a Fisheye Camera in Blender Cycles but now I need to change the whole scene to Blender Render. I have already converted the textures and material nodes so that's not a problem, *the problem is that the camera I made is a fisheye camera. This is the actual setup I made for it:*

[image]

In Cycles, the camera works perfectly but in Blender Render the settings just dissapear and the camera deformation for Fisheye doesn't work anymore.
I remember that keeping the camera parameters was possible but I don't remember how...

How can I convert my camera from Blender Cycles to Blender Render without losing the already made setup?

Comment: For fisheye on blender internal you can use a fisheye-camera-rig like this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blendertarium/_4n-AwZ6Bs4 more on it's use: https://vimeo.com/52084855

Comment: Can i import it somehow to my actual Blender file withoyt any problem?